# How to call the ApplicationController helper method in model? RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, helpermethods, applicationcontroller

Guys I've a helper method in ApplicationController as follows

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  helper_method :current_user
end
```

And I want to call it in my model (say Project) as follows:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :update_other_tables

  private

  def update_other_tables
  # if project saves, Create a new insteance into User Projects
  @userproject=UserProject.new(
   :user_id=>User.current_user.id,
   :project_id=>self.id
  )
  @userproject.save
end
```

Here, I'm getting error like **undefined method `current_user'**
So, How to call the this method in model? please help me

Answer (score 1):

I would do it in the following way:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Assignment method
  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  # Returns the current user, nil otherwise
  def current_user
    @current_user
  end
end
```

Now when a user logs in you can set:
`current_user = the_user`

And from the point onwards you can do:
`current_user.id`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**not a ruby guy** but I am guessing the User here isnt referring to the User that is present in your controller namespace and that is why there is no method current_user on the object.. You probably need to pass the  User object to your helper method or just pass the id..

The above theory is from my experience dealing with something similar in .Net MVC so please correct me if I am wrong and I will delete the answer..

P.S: was too long of a comment